# JavaScript - deadline not resetting

Tags: javascript, reset, deadlines

Can anybody tell me why the deadline isn't reset once it is reached (i.e. the 'else' section)?

```
var timeInMinutes = 1;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());

var deadline = localStorage.deadline;
if(deadline) {
    deadline = new Date(deadline);
}else {
    deadline = new Date(Date.now() + timeInMinutes*60*1000);
    localStorage.deadline = deadline;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `localStorage.getItem()` `localStorage.setItem()` to access localStorage properties.

Comment: @Robusto, using `getItem()` and `setItem()` is recommended but not necessary.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  The first time through, the `else` statement will run because `deadline` is undefined.  All subsequent times, `deadline` will be defined, so only the `if` statement will run.  Where is the code to "reset" `deadline`?

Comment: The `else` statement is supposed to set/reset the deadline and then until that deadline is reached the `if` statement is carried out. Then once the deadline is reached the `else` statement is carried out resetting the deadline.

Comment: How should I implement this?

Comment: As in what would the code look like for the if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` statement will run only the first time, because `deadline` will always be "truthy" after that.

Since the `else` statement should run the first time and whenever the deadline has passed, change your `if` condition to this:

```
var deadline = localStorage.deadline;
if(deadline && new Date() < new Date(deadline)) {
  deadline = new Date(deadline);
} else {
  deadline = new Date(Date.now() + timeInMinutes*60*1000);
  localStorage.deadline = deadline;
}
```

That basically says, "If there's a deadline *and* we haven't hit it, keep using the current deadline.  Else, set a new deadline."